# Will the current drywall look better after I texture it?

Tags: drywall

We are in the middle of a project where new drywall is going up on three walls. The current walls does have some screw holes that I would fill. The taped joints are bubbling up so not a clean looking wall at all. I will be doing a slapbrush texture on the new wall and this current wall so it matches the rest of the house. Will this help hide these joints? Or am I just wasting my time and I should replace this wall too?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it never got a third pass; can still see either the bevel of the drywall, or it's a butt joint missing its fill (take a 12" trowel and ever so slightly bend it so that it will leave an imperceptible hump - then sand down the hump, but not all the way).

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly a quality finish - by texturing it you're just hiding a bad job.

If time permits, I'd rip off the old tape and most of that plaster/mud, and re-finish this wall in the same way you've done the other new walls.  That way your texturing has the same base to sit on, and more likely to age the same way as the new walls.

Comment: I do have the time. So you would recommend sanding that wall back down and removing the tape to start from scratch? The wall is small at about 75x95". I wonder if it would be faster to just take down the old drywall and start with new sheets?

Comment: @junta maybe - depends on how much money you have.  Tape and plaster are cheaper than new sheets of drywall, but there's reassurance having the same thing on all walls.  And you can run cables inside the wall before re-lining.